# Getting a 'Segmentation Fault' when executing a particular Django query

Tags: python, django, apache

I've never come across this before, but for some strange reason i am getting a Segmentation Fault when running a specific query in Django. On reading up about Segmentation Faults, it seems it might have something to do with the version of Expat that Apache and Python use (and that they are different), what i am unsure about though, is why it has never been a problem for me before? And what is it about my query that causes it to trigger that error?

I am hoping that it is a fault of the query. Is anyone able to shed any light onto this?

Failing Query below:

```
def run_account_checks():
    # First, do we have any users with zero PAYG?
    d = datetime.now()
    d = d-timedelta(days=14)
    userprofiles = UserProfile.objects.filter(Q(payg_credits__isnull=True) | Q(payg_credits__lt="3.50"))
    userprofiles = userprofiles.filter(Q(lastemailed_paygempty__lte=d) | Q(lastemailed_paygempty__isnull=True))
    userprofiles = userprofiles.filter(user__supplier__isnull=False)
    for up in userprofiles:
        if up.user and up.user.email:
            # Send email to user

            up.lastemailed_paygempty = datetime.now()
            up.save()
```

Comment: Which OS and Apache module do you use?

Comment: I'm on Windows and get a "Runtime error" message box (on the first request only). Might be a similar problem - haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Oh that's strange. Do you think it has anything to do with teh fact that i'm querying the UserProfile model directly. I did notice a few days ago that userprofile wasn't available to me as a sql join from the main User model.

Comment: My other thought, was that it could be something to do with the decimal field?

Comment: I assume this only happens with mod_wsgi, not with `manage.py runserver`, right?!

Comment: No clue, but obviously this has something to do with mod_wsgi. Maybe you should ask on their mailing list or file a bug.